# Applying Autotune to a Video

Tags: electronics, production, audio, autotune

I would like to auto-tune a video, but I do not know how. Please tell me how I can achieve that effect.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific on what exactly you want to do to the video? Align all frequencies to one note and its octaves? Tune to a certain scale or other set of frequencies? Just manipulate certain specific elements?

Answer (score 4):

1: Export the audio, you want the audio exclusively, and you want it in lossless format (wav, aiff, flac) (unless your DAW in the next step supports video). You might need a video editing tool for this one.

2: Import the audio to a DAW: protools, live, logic, nuendo, whatever.

3: Apply auto-tune.

4: If your DAW can't deal with video, you need to glue back the video and audio using a video editing tool.

The question is very board as is though, so it's hard to help you further.

Or perhaps there's a video editing tool that supports audio plugins? If this is the case, you just have to load autotune (or other pitch corrector) into the video editing tool and you are done!

Comment: Let's hope it's not polyphonic ;-) I'm not envisioning anyone learning Melodyne in an afternoon ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin I haven't tried polyphonic features of pitch correction in years! Last time I tried they were somewhat accurate in very narrow, specific, scenarios, and completely off in everything else. Wonder if they are any better now, maybe someone threw machine learning at it or something.

Comment: It's not something I've really played with in a long time either. I used to use Melodyne for some pretty intricate editing - changing phrasing rather than just pitch, but a full-blown re-harm, no. It has been done though - this is probably the most famous example - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y6KmiIq2-m8 It takes your ears a minute to get used to it, especially if you already know the original song well.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that, if the file contains multiple tracks, or some encoded 5.1 type sound, there may be a bit more work involved in dealing with the audio.